how to create HTML table action using JSON string/array
I have an Excel workbook where I have Status Report which I have to copy in outlook and send it to respective stakeholders every day. I would like to automate this via power automate. For this, I have written an office script which will return values as JSON string. How can I use this JSON string to create HTML table action and finally use Send an email action.
I tried generating HTML output via excel script, but that is not giving me the exact formatting that I want to achieve.
